# CMake - Could not find boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to generate the VS project for a cpp program but CMake is failing with the errors:

> CMake Error at
>   C:/Users/fabio.rezende/Documents/cmake-3.13.3-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100
>   (message):   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.67.0
>
> Boost include path: C:/boost_1_67_0/include/boost-1_67
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>       boost_program_options
>       boost_system
> ```
>
> No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
>   to the   directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the
>   location of   Boost. Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)

**I've already tried the solutions proposed** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20656791/2414842) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386859/2414842) and none worked so now I'm literally clueless of what may be happening here. I've downloaded boost 1.67.0 from the [official website](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_67_0.html) compiled (with bootstrap.bat + b2 commands) installed with bjam as in the second link was proposed and placed it under `C:\`. The Cmake file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(BlockChainChat VERSION 1.0.0) 

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(BOOST_ROOT "C:\\boost_1_67_0")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "${BOOST_ROOT}\\stage\\lib")

find_package(Boost 1.67.0 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED system)
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

add_subdirectory(util)

add_executable(BlockChainChat main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(BlockChainChat LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(BlockChainChat PRIVATE util)
```

Note: without the SET BOOST_ROOT and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR I can easily build it under a linux machine.

Comment: I had a detailed answer that didn't required changing the cmake file at all. Here's how I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585302/2104697

Comment: Rerun CMake with `Boost_DEBUG` set, as described in that [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280823/cmake-not-finding-boost#comment18105824_13280823). It will show exact directories and files, which are searched for Boost. Check that you have these files in your Boost installation.